# indexPathForSelectedRow returns unexpected nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array called `Objects` which are a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and display their properties in a `UITableView`.

I have one segue to see the details of the object, which is performed using a gesture - this works fine until I use the `prepareForSegue` to pass the data of the `UITableViewCell` to the segueing `ViewController`. However when using
 `let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForSelectedRow`,
I am getting a nil value for the selected row so therefore the application crashes when trying to pass the data. Here is an example with the full code:

```
if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController         
    let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForSelectedRow
    if indexPath == nil { print(index path is NIL")}
    let selectedObject = self.objects[indexPath!.row]   
    vc.setting = setting
    vc.selectedObject = selectedObject          
}
```

Does anyone know what may be going wrong ? I have done the same thing in another ViewController and it worked fine. Also I was trying to implement another segue for when the cell is selected, but I cannot call `prepareForSegue` using the function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but can in my other `ViewController` - I am not sure if this information is relevant or may also indicate what the problem may be.

Comment: How is the segue triggered?

Comment: @vacawama The segue to pass the data on for `objectDetails` does work and is done via a gesture. The other gesture I was trying to implement for a segue I was trying to perform when selecting the cell.

Comment: Just to confirm, is self.table != nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having no cell selected is a valid condition. You should code defensively to handle that case. You could implement the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` method, and return `false` if `indexPathForSelectedRow` returns nil